# Tagging the directories and switching between them by tags - follow-up (Part 2/2: business logic)

Tags: bash, console, file-system

This is the `bash` script responsible for changing the directories via textual tags. ([See here the entire project.](https://github.com/coderodde/linux.directory_tagger))

**dt_script**

```
~/.dt/dt $@ > ~/.dt/dt_tmp
COMMAND_TYPE=$(head -n 1 ~/.dt/dt_tmp)
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    NEXT_PATH=$(~/.dt/dt prev | tail -n 1) # Let dt return pwd if no prev tag.
    ~/.dt/dt --update-prev $(pwd)
    if [ "$COMMAND_TYPE" == "message" ]; then
        tail -n 1 ~/.dt/dt_tmp
    else
        cd $NEXT_PATH
    fi
else
    if [ "$COMMAND_TYPE" == "switch_directory" ]; then
        NEXT_PATH=$(tail -n 1 ~/.dt/dt_tmp)
        ~/.dt/dt --update-prev $(pwd)
        cd $NEXT_PATH
    elif [ "$COMMAND_TYPE" == "show_tag_entry_list" ]; then
        tail -n +2 ~/.dt/dt_tmp  
    elif [ "$COMMAND_TYPE" == "message" ]; then
        tail -n 1 ~/.dt/dt_tmp
        #echo $(cut -d " " -f 2)
    else
        echo "Unknown command: $COMMAND_TYPE"
    fi
fi
rm ~/.dt/dt_tmp
```

Any further suggestions for improvement are welcomed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some suggestions:

- [Use More Quotes™](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes)

  - `$@` should be double quoted to pass the parameters without word splitting.
  - *Any* variable use should be quoted. It is very rare that word splitting is actually what you want, and it causes sometimes very subtle bugs.
  - [Command substitution](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution) should be quoted.
- Use [good bashisms](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3427872/96588) such as `[[` instead of `[`.
- Local variables should be lowercase to distinguish them from system variables, which are uppercase.
- There is no need for semicolons in Bash scripts. This may be more contentious, but I generally write like this:

  ```
  if [[ "$variable" = 'value' ]]
  then
      …
  ```

  Apropos: `==` to compare strings is a bit of a historical accident. The original operator is just `=`, but `==` is probably not going away.
- `$(pwd)` can be simplified to `.` - it also means the current directory.
- The home directory should not be used for temporary file storage (unless that is actually your configured temporary directory). In general you should use something like `working_dir="$(mktemp --directory)"` (or `-d` if you don't have GNU coreutils `mktemp`). This has a few advantages:

  - It means your home directory isn't going to fill up with temporary files which are never cleaned up (but more about that below).
  - It is often a memory mapped filesystem, so it may be much faster than your home directory.
- Long `if`/`elif` sections testing the value of a single variable can usually be easier written as a `case` block.
- `head` does *not* fail if run on an empty file:

  ```
  $ touch foo
  $ head foo
  $ echo $?
  0
  ```

  So your first test could fail for the wrong reason. You might want to `[[ -s "$path" ]]` to check if a file is empty.
- The file name "dt_tmp" doesn't tell me anything about what it contains or what it's used for - in general I find that adding the project name to *anything* within the project is redundant, and marking something as temporary is not particularly helpful to know what it *is,* unless it really can contain anything. Is there a better name you can give it? It looks like it's some sort of command queue, maybe?